# Tkinter .pack() window not showing?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, window, tk-toolkit

I've been working on a simple program that make a button output something. But when i run it, 
this[image]

(I got this from the internet btw) does not show up. Is somethoing wrong with the code or something? 
Please help me so the window above can appear :)

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *
def asdf():
    print('test')
tk = Tk()
b = Button(tk, text="test", command=asdf)
b.pack()
```

Comment: I don't see any reason to downvote on this. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to call the [`Tk.mainloop`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.mainloop-method) method at the end of your program:

```
from Tkinter import *
def asdf():
    print('test')
tk = Tk()
b = Button(tk, text="test", command=asdf)
b.pack()
##############
tk.mainloop()
##############
```

Doing so starts Tkinter's main event loop and creates the window.

Comment: Some operating systems or environments do not need a call to `mainloop` to run the program..

Comment: @Broly - Yea, I think *nix systems do not require this.  But it looks like the OP is running Windows, where this is required.

Comment: @iCodez: not correct. *all* systems require that the mainloop be running. However, some environments (such as IDLE) will start it for you. If you are writing a script that must be able to be run from a command line, you always need to call `mainloop`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Python3, as there are parentheses after print, so `from Tkinter import *` should be `from tkinter import *`. Python is case-sensitive. You also forgot to call `root.mainloop()` at the end of your code as @user2555451 mentioned, although a window should appear all the same, but stop responding when any event occurs (e.g., clicks, key presses, focus changes) or briefly appear before closing itself.